# Send data between 2 fragments, sharedPreferences Kotlin

Tags: android, kotlin, fragment, sharedpreferences, send

I am currently building an app, in my app's setting, there is an option that you can set the password for the app. If the user sets a password, the next time he or she opens the app, the app is locked. I saved the password via sharePerfenses.
What I did:

```
   private fun createPassword() {
    val passKey = "Password"
    val sharedPreference =
        requireActivity().getSharedPreferences(passKey, Context.MODE_PRIVATE)
    var editor = sharedPreference.edit()
    editor.putString("password", mSetPasswordBinding.password.text.toString())
    editor.putBoolean("passwordStatus", true)
    editor.apply()
}
```

Now I want to send the password that the user has set in the setting to log in screen.

CreatePasswordFragment:

```
class CreatePasswordFragment : DialogFragment() {
lateinit var mSetPasswordBinding: FragmentCreatePasswordBinding

override fun onCreateView(
    inflater: LayoutInflater, container: ViewGroup?,
    savedInstanceState: Bundle?
): View? {
    // Inflate the layout for this fragment
    mSetPasswordBinding =
        DataBindingUtil.inflate(
            layoutInflater,
            R.layout.fragment_create_password,
            container,
            false
        )
    mSetPasswordBinding.submit.setOnClickListener {
        checkPassword()
    }
    mSetPasswordBinding.clear.setOnClickListener {
        clear()
    }
    val passKet = "Password"
    val sharedPreference =
        requireActivity().getSharedPreferences(passKet, Context.MODE_PRIVATE)
    sharedPreference.getString("password", "defaultName")
    mSetPasswordBinding.submit.text = sharedPreference.getString("password", "")

    if (sharedPreference.getBoolean("passwordStatus", false)) {
        mSetPasswordBinding.passwordStatus.text = "تغییر رمز"

    }
    return mSetPasswordBinding.root
}

    private fun checkPassword(): Boolean {
    val getEditTextValue = mSetPasswordBinding.password.text.toString()
    val getRepeatEditTextValue = mSetPasswordBinding.repeat.text.toString()

    if (getEditTextValue != getRepeatEditTextValue) {
        mSetPasswordBinding.repeatL.error = "رمز با تکرار ان مطابقت ندارد."
    } else {
        mSetPasswordBinding.repeatL.error = null
        createPassword()
        Toast.makeText(activity, "رمز با موفقیت ثبت شد.", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show()
        findNavController().popBackStack()
        return true
    }
    return true
}

   private fun createPassword() {
    val passKey = "Password"
    val sharedPreference =
        requireActivity().getSharedPreferences(passKey, Context.MODE_PRIVATE)
    var editor = sharedPreference.edit()
    editor.putString("password", mSetPasswordBinding.password.text.toString())
    editor.putBoolean("passwordStatus", true)
    editor.apply()
}

private fun clear() {
    val passKey = "Password"
    val passStatus = "passwordStatus"
    val sharedPreference =
        requireActivity().getSharedPreferences(passKey, Context.MODE_PRIVATE)
    val sharedPreferencePasswordStatus =
        requireActivity().getSharedPreferences(passStatus, Context.MODE_PRIVATE)
    sharedPreference.edit().clear().apply()
    sharedPreferencePasswordStatus.edit().clear().apply()
}
```

Receiver Class:

```
class LockScreenFragment : Fragment() {

override fun onCreateView(
    inflater: LayoutInflater, container: ViewGroup?,
    savedInstanceState: Bundle?
): View? {
    // Inflate the layout for this fragment

    return inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_lock_screen, container, false)
}
```

}

And finally create password layout:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<layout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">

<LinearLayout xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="@drawable/for_pop_up_square"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:id="@+id/t1"
    tools:context=".ui.createPassword.CreatePasswordFragment">

    <FrameLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content">

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="50dp"
            android:id="@+id/passwordStatus"
            android:layout_marginLeft="2dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
            android:layout_marginRight="2dp"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:text="رمز ورود"
            android:textColor="@color/black"
            android:textSize="20sp" />
    </FrameLayout>

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginLeft="20sp"
        android:layout_marginTop="20sp"
        android:layout_marginRight="20sp"
        android:orientation="vertical">

        <com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputLayout
            android:id="@+id/cardNumberLt"
            style="@style/Widget.MaterialComponents.TextInputLayout.OutlinedBox"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:hint="رمز ورود">
            <!--this is the actual edit text which takes the input-->
            <com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputEditText
                android:id="@+id/password"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:inputType="textPassword" />
        </com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputLayout>
    </LinearLayout>

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginLeft="20sp"
        android:layout_marginTop="20sp"
        android:layout_marginRight="20sp"
        android:orientation="vertical">

        <com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputLayout
            android:id="@+id/repeatL"
            style="@style/Widget.MaterialComponents.TextInputLayout.OutlinedBox"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:hint="تکرار رمز ورود">
            <!--this is the actual edit text which takes the input-->
            <com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputEditText
                android:id="@+id/repeat"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:inputType="textPassword" />
        </com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputLayout>
    </LinearLayout>

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginLeft="20sp"
        android:layout_marginTop="20sp"
        android:layout_marginRight="20sp"
        android:layout_marginBottom="30sp"
        android:orientation="vertical">

        <com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputLayout
            android:id="@+id/rememberl"
            style="@style/Widget.MaterialComponents.TextInputLayout.OutlinedBox"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:hint="یادآور">
            <!--this is the actual edit text which takes the input-->
            <com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputEditText
                android:id="@+id/remember"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:inputType="textPassword" />
        </com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputLayout>
    </LinearLayout>

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/submit"
        android:layout_marginLeft="30dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="30dp"
        android:text="تایید"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" />
    <Button
        android:id="@+id/clear"
        android:layout_marginLeft="30dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="30dp"
        android:text="حذف"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" />
</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: If I understood well, the `SharedPreference` can be accessed from any part of your app that has a context; no need to share it between fragments/activities

Comment: Yes, now I got it, I thought It was like live data and database THANKS

Comment: Not directly related to your question, but you really shouldn't be storing passwords in plain text on the device like this. Consider using the new security feature added in Jetpack: https://developer.android.com/topic/security/data

Comment: I will check it out